# How to convert or decode the Unicode characters in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, unicode, data-analysis

I was reading some data from an excel file using pandas and did some row traversal to make a python dictionary which i then put into a json file .

The problem is that I am getting Unicode characters in the json file itself :

```
"C V M College of Fine Arts,\u00a0 Vallabh Vidyanagar"
```

As shown above I don't want the Unicode '\u00a0' and instead want the decoded character representation of it in my json file.

Is there any way I can do this conversion (or filtering or whatever its called) while reading the excel file from the pandas itself ? or is there any way to do this while writing to json file using `json.dump()`?

Comment: That character is a "non-breaking space". [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)`:

```
foo = "C V M College of Fine Arts,\u00a0 Vallabh Vidyanagar"

import json
print(json.dumps({'foo':foo}, ensure_ascii=False))
```

returns:

```
{"foo": "C V M College of Fine Arts,  Vallabh Vidyanagar"}
```